# Is there a way to create an object and assign it a dynamic property simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

This might be a silly question, but I'm looking for a nice and compact way to both create an object, using the object literal notation, and assign it a dynamic property.

Right now, I'm doing it like this:

```
var foo = "lol";
var obj = {};
obj[foo] = "bar";
return obj;

// --> returns {lol:"bar"}
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var foo = "lol";
return ({}[foo] = "bar");

// --> returns {lol:"bar"}
```

Is there some kind of pattern to do this? I'm not too concerned about readability, although I'm looking for something compact if possible.

I can do it this way but it's pretty big, and pretty much exactly like splitting the statement into multiple lines.

```
var foo = "lol", obj;
return (obj = {}) && (obj[foo] = "bar") && obj;
```

Comment: I think your best bet would be to just create a function which assigns the property.

Comment: @Arun: (1) That's invalid  JS. (2) The property name is not dynamic.

Comment: yes. sorry my mistake

Comment: Have a try on using eval, its not eval as long as you know what string you are passing in

Comment: up me if it is cool solution. 
Object.prototype.push = function( key, value ){
   this[ key ] = value;
   return this;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a huge fan of function-based answers, I'd rather have some kind of expression.

I came up with more compact form:

```
var obj, foo = "lol";
return ((obj = {})[foo] = "bar") && obj;
```

It would be cool if I could have the `var obj` inside the expression. Not sure how. It would be ultimate if I didn't have to define the `obj` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple function that takes in name:value pairs as successive arguments, something like:

```
function dataBlob() {
  var args = arguments;
  for(var x = 0; x < arguments.length -1; x=x+2) {       
   this[args[x]] = args[x+1];
  }
  return this;
}
```

Which, assuming my JavaScript hasn't atrophied to the point the above is senseless, could be used as :

```
var obj = dataBlob("lol","bar", "lolz", 42);
```

which would be equivalent to the JSON-esque

```
var obj = {lol:"bar", lolz:42};
```

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/4L77g/)***

You are looking for [Object.defineProperty <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method. You can define a new object and the assign the dynamic property using it.

```
function test(){
 var foo = "lol";
 return Object.defineProperty({},foo,{value:"bar"});    
}

alert(test().lol);
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSFidle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/73nHd/)

You can add this method to Object.prototype to get great functionality:

```
Object.prototype.push = function( key, value ){
   this[ key ] = value;
   return this;
}

var foo = "lol";
var obj = {};
obj.push(foo, "bar")

=>
Object {lol: "bar", push: function}
```